# Calculating values in dict using 'for' loop

Tags: python, dictionary, calculation

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to solve the following task: I need to calculate the total amount of Fanta, Lavazza, Lipton etc. consumed in litres (7140 litres is the correct answer) using the following information:

```
brandnames = { "Fanta", "Lavazza", "Lipton", "Coke", "Evian", "Nescafe", "Twinings", "Volvic", 
           "Perrier" }

drinks = { "Fanta": "soda", "Lavazza": "coffee", "Lipton": "tea", "Coke": "soda", "Evian": "water",               
       "Nescafe": "coffee", "Twinings": "tea", "Volvic": "water", "Perrier": "water" }

type = { "soda", "tea", "coffee", "water" }

amount_in_litres = { "soda": "550", "tea": "500", "water": "1200", "coffee": "720" }
```

I tried the following:

```
amount = 0

for brand in brandnames:
    drink = drinks[brand]      
    quota = amount_in_litres[drink] 
    amount = amount + quota

    print(amount, "litres consumed.")
```

but I get the following error message: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. I'm not even sure if I should include an if-statement to solve the problem or what I should do. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: amount _in_litres stores the values in string format. you cannot add the amount ( integer type) with the quota ( string type). Convert quota to integer format before addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your quota to int

```
amount=amount+int(quota)
```

If u want total one line then please deindent(remove print statement inside for loop because it will print every time loop iterates) and print outside loop

```
for brand in brandnames:
    drink = drinks[brand]      
    quota = amount_in_litres[drink] 
    amount = amount + int (quota)
print(amount, "litres consumed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access `amount_in_litres[drink]` you are getting `str`, since your dictionary is:

```
amount_in_litres = { "soda": "550", "tea": "500", "water": "1200", "coffee": "720" }
```

You want to change it to:

```
quota = int(amount_in_litres[drink])
```

so `quota` will be `int` typed.

Answer (score -1):

Your `amount_in_litres` dictionary contains numbers as strings, e.g. "550". Replace them with numbers without quotation marks, e.g. 550.